# Why are my line numbers restarting at 1 in each section even though I've chosen 'continuous'?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007, numbering

Using MS Word 2007. I have 5 sections. Sections 2 and 4 have line-numbering turned on, and I've chosen "continuous' (and not 'restart each section'). However, both sections begin line numbers at 1. In other words, it's acting as though I'd chosen 'restart each section'.

Is this a bug, or is there something here I don't understand?

Comment: When you say you have line numbering turned on, do you mean you have a numbered list?

Comment: I'm not talking about numbered lists, I'm talking about SECTIONS with line-numbering turned on.

Answer (score 1):

It's 2017 and I'm having the same problem with Word 2010.  The workaround I did find was to include the entire passage to be numbered, from the very first to the very last, *including any sections that you do not want numbered*.  In the example in the question, you would line numbers to sections 2-4.

Then, to *remove* line numbers from the paragraphs that shouldn't have them, select those paragraphs and select Line Numbers --> Suppress Line Numbers.  In the example above, you would select section 3 and "Suppress Line Numbers" for that section.  When you do that, section 4 line numbers should pick up where section 2 left off.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the problem.  Perhaps there is some other special formatting going on?
In general I fix the numbering in one of two ways:

1. Right click on the second numbered list (eg, right click on the "1."), and choose "Continue Numbering".
2. If #1 doesn't work, you can specify what number to start on by right clicking on a number and choosing "Set numbering value".  From there you can set what the list item number is--and the others will follow (at least in that section).
3. Usually when I continue a numbered list, I simply type the next number (eg "8.") and Word figures out that I am continuing the previous list.

I'm taking a blind stab in the dark since I can't see the same problem you're experiencing--Word seems to figure it out for me without any trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Just type whatever number you want and followed by . & space. Automatically word will correct the numbering